# Check for NaN value and go to debugging python

Tags: python, debugging, nan

I want to check during the execution of the code if a value is NaN and if it is to go to a debug-like mode to check why is this happening. Is this possible?

Something like that:

```
if np.isnan(value):
    stop and go to the screen to check the variables
```

Comment: Have you looked into [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)? Also you should use this snippet within your check for NaN in order to break into the debugger `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set a breakpoint at this point in your script. Checkout [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for debugging.